# Merge a group of set of columns into one single "set of columns" in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

**Problem context:**

I am creating a Google spreadsheet to help me track the status of different characters progression in a game, call it DFFOO.

The game splits the characters by crystal color, and I would like to make use of this to ease the task of finding a character and knowing its status of board farming.

Here is an example:

Sheet **IFRIT farming**

Contains current status for IFRIT summon board farming status, {n=none, r=rewarded, m=mastered}

```
| Black  | Status | Red     | Status | ...
| Squall | m      | Vanille | r      | 
| Noctis | n      | Another | r      |
```

Sheet **SHIVA farming**

Contains current status for SHIVA summon board farming status, {n=none, r=rewarded, m=mastered}

```
| Black  | Status | Red     | Status | ...
| Squall | r      | Vanille | r      | 
| Noctis | n      | Another | r      |
```

Sheet **Character release**

Contains information about new banners for the game, the characters have a period of time where they get double experience, this states the current status of the different board and when the "x2" ends (End boosted) to help me plan ahead.

```
| Character  | IFRIT | SHIVA | ...  | End boosted | 
| Squall     | m     |   r   | ...  |   21-Oct    |
| Vanille    | r     |   r   | ...  |   10-Oct    |
```

**My problem**

There is one place where a very weird formula needs to be in place:

**Option 1**

In each "farming" sheet, I add a formula that JOINS all the pair columns into a single pair-column.

I tried this on row1, column Y:

```
=FILTER({C3:D;E3:F;G3:H;I3:J;K3:L;M3:N;O3:P;Q3:R},LEN({C3:D;E3:F;G3:H;I3:J;K3:L;M3:N;O3:P;Q3:R}))
```

The problem with this approach is that FILTER can only match 1 column, and not a range, so this does not work.

PRO is that on the Character sheet I only need to do a VLOOKUP over that created range, and on the farming sheet I can hide column Y and ab so it is transparent to the sheet.

**Option 2:**

Only one modification needs to be done on the Character sheet, which is a VLOOKUP, it works fine but the formula gets super complicated with all the semi-colons referencing another sheet with multiple ranges.

I would like to have a solution that works for Option 1, so I only need to apply a weird formula on the farming sheet, I can hide those columns but use them to ease the formula on the Character Release sheet, imho this is a cleaner solution and scales well.

Another pro point for this is, whenever I finally have this working, I would like to show to DFFOO community in case they want to use it (this is actually an extension of an idea I saw) and having complicated formulas make it difficult to extend.

If anyone can help me on figuring out a solution to join a set of different columns into one "set of columns" would be perfect.

added an excel with expectations: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15L5nPGfZ8OXS5Rhl3PdIVhtF7D3QzerkARskflDiJL4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your shet with example of desired output

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15L5nPGfZ8OXS5Rhl3PdIVhtF7D3QzerkARskflDiJL4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can join any number of columns into one single column by using a `QUERY` smash:

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:D),,999^99))
```

will merge columns A, B, C and D into one single column

then you can safely put it into `FILTER` let's say via regex like:

```
=FILTER(G:H, REGEXMATCH(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A:D),,999^99)), "abc|def|xxx"))
```

this would filter range G:H where any of the joint columns (A:D) contain at least one of 3 possible strings (abc or def or xxx)

---

## UPDATE:

```
={"Character", "Status"; 
 ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(A2:H<>"", 
 IF(MOD(COLUMN(A2:H), 2)=0, "♠"&A2:H, "♦"&A2:H), ))
 ,,999^99)),,999^99)), "♦")), "♠"))}
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried this but does not really solves my problem, I would like to have in H and I (two different columns) a join of A2:B, C2:D and E2:F (without checking duplicates atm as they should not exist). Then from a different Sheet I can query H and I with a VLOOKUP

Comment: weird formula as I said, it gives that error though: In ARRAY_LITERAL: An Array literal was missing values for one or more rows

Comment: your skills are second to none, thanks a lot player0