# SUMPRODUCT & Row Alternative

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using the following formula to get the row number with a specific text from in a Google Sheet. But the sheet has become heavy with the usage of SUMPRODUCT. How can I replace SUMPRODUCT with a better performing function?

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(ROW(INDIRECT("'"&$P3&"'!"&"A:D"))*(INDIRECT("'"&$P3&"'!"&"A:D")="text abc"))=0,"",SUMPRODUCT(ROW(INDIRECT("'"&$P3&"'!"&"A:D"))*(INDIRECT("'"&$P3&"'!"&"A:D")="text abc")))
```

Comment: Do you have some sample data with desired results in the form of a sheet you can share and we can use?

Comment: The question is tagged as [google-sheets]. If you need help with Microsoft Excel instead, tag the question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()` with a [query smush](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/85111204?msgid=85209465), like this:

```
=filter( 
  row(indirect($P3 & "!A1:D")), 
  search( 
    "text abc", 
    transpose(query(transpose(indirect($P3 & "!A1:D")), "", 9^9)) 
  ) 
)
```

The formula will return the row numbers of all rows where `text abc` appears in any column in `A1:D`.

Comment: I do wonder who dared to misspell it as "smush" lol and at what stage... Oct 10, 2019 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58327224/5632629

Comment: Oh, the query smush was discovered by [Isai](https://web.archive.org/web/20150221193151/http://isaialvarado.com/) at the Google Docs Productforum in the summer of 2014. See the [group archive](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/d/msgid/docs/e6bfdd3a-a0a3-418f-b01d-60fd2825bd67%40googleproductforums.com).